# FlowDocument - Reset bring into view

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport

I have a following code in my XAML file:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="fd_ScrollViewer" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <FlowDocument PagePadding="10" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="21.5">
            <Paragraph Name="fdParagraph"></Paragraph>
      </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

For a Paragraph component, in behind code, I initialize paragraph with a big text of type Run, where from time to time I bring into view to Run elements.
However, my problem is I can not reset viewport to the start of the content.
Here is what I tried:

```
    private void ResetBringIntoView() {
        // current run element is Run element with 0 Index in Paragraph Inline
        if (fdParagraph.FlowDirection == System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight) {
            fdParagraph.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            CurrentRunElement.BringIntoView();
        }         
        else {
            fdParagraph.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            CurrentRunElement.BringIntoView();
        }
    }
```

But this didn't worked.